# Calculating block diagonalization / canonical bases with linear optimization?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition, numerical-optimization

**Edit** Even though I have started answering my own question I am still eager to hear any feedback and new ideas. So feel free to tell me if you come to think of anything.

---

In Linear Algebra there are many types of similarity transformations $${\bf A} = {\bf T}^{-1}{\bf DT}$$
Where $\bf D$ is (block-)diagonal. Famous examples include Eigenvalue decompositions, Jordan Normal Form and in matrix representation theory of groups a fully reduced representation:
$${\bf A}_k = {\bf T}^{-1}{{\bf D}_k{\bf T}}, \hspace{0.5cm} {\bf A}_k \hspace{0.25cm} \text{represents group element} \hspace{0.25cm} g_k$$

Where all the ${\bf D}_k$ have some pairwise same block sizes (but not same block content).

Anyway there exist many algorithms to calculate $\bf T$ and $\bf D$. I had an idea of an approach which I don't know if it has been tried, so I was thinking to ask you if you think it has already been done or some feedback if it would be practical or useful to do or not.

If we rewrite $\bf TA = DT$ or even $\bf TA -DT = 0$ then we will be getting an equation system with an equation for each resulting element of these products. It will be linear in $\bf T$ and in $\bf D$ if we consider them separately. Now we can impose constraints  to encourage $\bf D$ to be sparse in a block-like way. If we add a penalty ${\bf W}\|\text{vec}({\bf D})\|_k$, where ${\bf W}_{lm} = g(|i-j|)\delta_{l-m}$ correspond to ${\bf D}_{ij}$ in $\text{vec}({\bf D})_l$, say $g(x)$ monotonically increasing and $k$ is some suitable Schatten norm.

Also note that we can replace the equality with an optimization cost: $${\bf TA-DT=0} \to \min_{{\bf D, T}}\left\{\|{\bf TA-DT}\|\right\}$$ and in the case we have two sequences of matrices: $$\{{\bf A}_1 , \cdots, {\bf A}_n \}\hspace{1cm}\{{\bf D}_1 , \cdots, {\bf D}_n\}$$we could just add them upp : $$\min_{{\bf D_l, T}}\left\{\sum_l\|{\bf TA}_l - {\bf D}_l{\bf T}\|\right\}$$

Now we can try to:

1. Initialize $\bf T$ and $\bf D$(s) to some initial state. For example some random distribution.

Alternatingly solve:

2. Optimization with respect to $\bf T$ given current $\bf D$(s).
3. Optimization with respect to $\bf D$(s) given current $\bf T$.

Stop if solutions fluctuate much ( to restart at better point ) or if they converge ( to accept the solution ).

Maybe we will need to have a tiny regularizer keeping down the total norm of $\bf D$(s) and $\bf T$ when solving the respective equation. We can do this linearly for $k=2$ and for $k\neq 2$ by iterated reweighting. So if it works, we would in fact get away with solving a sequence of linear equation systems.

Could this be a useful approach or are there reasons why it will refuse to work (at all) or why it will be unfeasible to perform the calculations ( considering speed of our convergence and other things )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not having found any reason for why this should not work, I could not resist trying it.

**Initial investigations**

Letting $\bf A = RR^T, R \in \mathcal{N}(\mathbb{R}^{n\times n})$ will guarantee $\bf A$ to be diagonalizable with $\lambda_k({\bf A})\in \mathbb{R}^+$.

We use the [vectorization formula with Kronecker products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29) to turn the matrices into vectors.

Furthermore, let $$\text{unvec}(\bf W) = 1_n{1_n}^T-(1-\epsilon) I_n$$

specify our weight-matrix. In other words off diagonals in $\bf D$ cost $1$ and diagonals $\epsilon$.

Please note that **no regularization is done for the T** phase. Could explain jumpyness in the convergence.

In the plots below : $n=4$, $\epsilon = 10^{-3}$ The level of the "floor" we are hitting seems to be a function of $\epsilon$.

[image]
[image]

---

Setting ${\bf A} = {\bf R}, {\bf R} \in \mathcal{N}(\mathbb{R}^{n\times n})$ also works, and we do get results converging to the same eigenvectors and eigenvalues as octave "eig" gives, but **only if we initiate D and T with non-zero imaginary part**. This is not strange as real numbers are closed under addition and multiplication and a sequence of those operations (and their inverses) are the only ones which the iterative method uses!